# HVDC - High Voltage DC generation

Tags: circuit-design, high-voltage

n my application I've to generate HVDC(~700V) for firing of ultrasonic probes to generate RF signal. Here is the circuit diagram i'm using:
[image]

I'm generating two differential square wave(complemented) which will drive N channel MOSFET ([RSS100N03](http://www.siongboon.com/projects/2006-06-19_switch/n-ch%20rss100n03.pdf)) +5V is generated from battery through (LM1117-5 regulator )

EDITS:
Further Details:

Square wave is of frequency ~40-50kHz

U22 is NAND gate [SN74LV00](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lv00.pdf)

1. can someone tell me how HVDC is getting generate  here, since as far as I know Transformer works on AC only?
2. What does RSS1000N03 do here?
3. Is there any other concept/circuit to generate HVDC from low DC?

Comment: Do you really have a capacitor of 4.7kF, or am I failing the sight test?

Comment: it's actually 4.7Kpf..

Comment: @nkg2743: 4.7Kpf means 4.7 kelvin pico something. "k" for kilo, "K" for kelvin, "p" for pico, "F" for farad. Capitals matter. See SI units.

Comment: The square wave **IS** AC. | What frequency is the square wave. Unless VERY low frequency things need changing. | What part number is U22? | Make R12, R13 VERY low to get max gate drive CURRENT to FETS. - say a few Ohms - maybe 10 Ohms. R14 R15 should not be needed except if U22 is open collector - which it should NOT be. | How did you dimension R25. | How much power do the probes need. Average and peak? | What is spec of TR1 (web link?) turns ratio. How was it chosen? ||There are many ways to make HVDC but what you actually need needs knowing.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon can you provide me few links where I can get more insight about the topic

Comment: How much output power? Have you considered a simple flyback for the task?

Comment: @nkg2743 Yes. But, why not answer the questions asked? || -  What frequency is the square wave. | - What part number is U22? | - How did you dimension R25. | - How much power do the probes need. Average and peak? | - What is spec of TR1 (web link?)  | - turns ratio. | - How was it chosen? || AND make these changes and/or ask why: - 
| Make R12, R13 VERY low to get max gate drive CURRENT to FETS. - say a few Ohms - maybe 10 Ohms. | - R14 R15 should not be needed except if U22 is open collector. 

**There are many ways to make HVDC but what you actually need needs knowing**

Comment: square wave frequency is ~40-50kHz. U22 is SN74LV00 link is added in the question later on. TR1 specs are P1:P2:S = 24:24:1000 turns. It's already used in our organization for generating HV(600-700V). I don't have more details of it.And Surely, I'll test my output by making R12 & R13 low. R25 is 10k 0.5W resistor (I didn't get you when you say how you dimension R25). Probes are not fixed, they change as per application and I have to fire probes depending upon the frequency of probe used for different applications. (I'm new so learning things. I don't know about avg & peak power of probes yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The high voltage in this system is generated from the high voltage secundary winding of the transformer followed by a voltage double circuit.
When the voltage from the transformer goes negative on connection 5 the capacitor C 58 is charged trough D48. When the transformer voltage goes positive on connection 5 the transformer voltage is in series with the capacitor voltage of C 58 and C59 will be charged at a double value trough D47.
The RSS 100NO3 are driving the transformer alternating each one half the square wave comming from the input.That is why the incomming square wave is inverted by the as inverter connected nor gates.

There are other possibilities to generate HV. but that you have to find yourself

Comment: what you explained is about after transformer but I'm more interested in what happens before transformer section and that's what question is about. I know arrangement of diode will form doubler/tripler.

Comment: @nkg2743: didn't you already tell in your question that you feed it a square wave?

Comment: Since you indicated that the transformer produces AC and your question is about AC to HVDC i explained the doubler. Anyway have added some info about the driving circuit.